# Can Wine share the install directory with Windows?

Tags: wine, home-directory, winetricks

I want to use Starcraft 2 with Wine, however it requires 18GB.  My home directory won't let me copy it to the Linux side because it says I'm out of space when there's over 60GB free.

I realize I'm sure there's a way for me to increase the available disc space... but is it ok for Wine to share the same install directory for Starcraft 2 as Windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I've been able to determine, it can.  There doesn't appear to be any modification happening to the installation files.

At least, this has worked for me in Starcraft 2.